# Jinja2 throwing templatedoesnotexist error in Django project

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm trying to use jinja2 in my Django project (ver 1.10). After setting it up, once I try to run the project, I get `TemplateDoesNotExist at /base/index.html` and

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine jinja2:
This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
```

In `templates` folder, I have a base directory where index.html is placed. Moreover, if I use Django's template engine, this same folder structure works perfectly. How can I fix this issue?

---

My config is as follows:

In `settings.py` (note that I've deliberately excluded the Django template fallback):

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {'environment': 'uberfordoc.jinja2.environment',
        }, 
    },
]
```

I also have a file called `jinja2.py` kept in the project folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import 
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

Comment: If you add "print os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')" to your settings.py file, does the output (in terminal) match your expectations?

Comment: @Timbadu It worked. There was an issue with setting up the path. It worked after I saw the output. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my BASE_DIR and MAIN_DIR in settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and my jinja2 templates were at the path

**/Users/username/Desktop/uberfordoc/templates/jinja2**

changed

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

to

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(MAIN_DIR, 'templates/jinja2')],
```

and it worked. Got the hint thanks to @Timbadu by printing

```
print os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

Comment: I didn't realize this setting was inside `TEMPLATES`, so I took a bit to fix. In my settings.py my `DIRS` was empty. After I set it to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` all worked. Thanks!